# Can't instantiate COM object from ASP.NET MVC app

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, com

As the title says, I want to instantiate a COM object from an ASP.NET MVC app like this:

```
dynamic obj = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID(progID));
```

but it throws the following ComException:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {16542E4F-4594-4B97-922D-BE9C478F93BB} failed due to the following
>   error: 800aea5f Exception from HRESULT: 0x800AEA5F.

The same code works from a Winforms app with the following build configuration: `Platform: x86` and `Platform target: x86`.

I set the build configuration the same as the Winforms app for both the mvc app and the assembly where I use the COM object.

I'm using Windows 7, IIS 7.5, ASP.NET v4.0 Application Pool with Enable 32-Bit Applications True and the website runs under a user with Administator rights.

What are your suggestions to help solve this problem?

Comment: Even if you have enabled 32bit mode, that doesn't mean your .NET Code runs in 32bit. So I guess it is you calling a 32bit COM from a 64bit .NET code?

Comment: @YvesR As i said in the question, I set the build configuration: `Platform: x86` and `Platform target: x86` for both the mvc app and the assembly where I use the COM object, so it should be running 32-bit code.

Comment: Did you set the DCOM rights correctly so you can start com+ objects from the web site? I mean the default start settings (dcomcnfg.exe) for the account you running on the website. I always need to adjust set when I setup IIS on win2k8 machines.

Comment: Check that Environment.Is64BitProcess is false to ensure you're in 32-bit code...

Comment: 800AEA5F does sound like a permissions problem.  When you say "website runs under a user with Administrator rights" are you talking about the Application Pool's Default User?

Comment: @YvesR I didn't set any DCOM rights. What DCOM rights do I need to set and how?

Comment: @PeterRitchie Environment.Is64BitProcess is set to false.

Comment: @PeterRitchie In IIS, My application -> Basic Settings -> Connect As -> Specific User (the user i set here has admin rights).

Comment: @PeterRitchie I tried changing the Application Pool's Default User to a user with admin rights and now it works, so please post an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: @david.s You really want to run a website with admin rights or just for testing? Otherwise setup dcom rights correct as I answered and it works as well!

Comment: @YvesR I tried your answer and it didn't work.

Comment: @david.s Well if you can run it with admin rights (default user app pool) then it is a proof that it is just a permission problem. Then you can run it with a normal user as well and setup this user with dcom rights. My screenshots may differ about username/groups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the Application Pool's Default User to a user with Admin rights

Answer (score 1):

@david.s I don't know how to add a screenshot as a comment, so I set it as an answer.
As you already have all 32bit stuff set and the DLL can't be called it might be a permission problem.

Call dcomcnfg.exe and check the settings (sorry, only german server, but should work):
[image]

You have to reset your IIS after settings change.