# ASP.Net MVC using existing COM objects as model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, com

We currently have a classic ASP web app using a set of COM objects that encompass the business logic and database access.
We are in the planning phase of our next rev an are looking at ASP.Net MVC 4 as the framework.
Can ASP.Net MVC use an existing COM object model through interop as the Model?  Or is it better to use WebForms.

Comment: Why don't you try to write a short MVC application to test it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ASP.NET MVC is a dev framework which does not worry what is your Data Access method is . It can be  an XML file or a REST API call result or your COM objects. What you need to do is to map your these objects to your `viewmodel` approproately. Create ViewModels as necessary to pass data to and from the Views.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use existing COM object model in asp.net here is a post how to do it [Can't instantiate COM object from ASP.NET MVC app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471856/cant-instantiate-com-object-from-asp-net-mvc-app)

If you can try to get rid of this COM object and rewrite in .net managed code

Few reason it can turn in to a bottle neck, cause performance issues and dependency

Also if you re-wrote it you will be able to do [Test Driven Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development)